# Why is the object not defined in this environment?

Tags: r, environment-variables

I have very little understanding of how environments work in R.

Here is my code

```
push = function(l, x)
{
  assign(l, append(eval(as.name(l)), x), envir=parent.frame())
}

main = function()
{
    mylist = list("hello")
    push("mylist","World")
}

main()
```

This code returns the error

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'mylist' not found
```

- Why does it return this error?
- How to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `eval` is not taking place with respect to the parent frame of the `push` call, only the `assign` is.

One could pass the `parent.frame()` to `eval` or adopt the following style which seems clearer.  (`main` is unchanged.)

```
push = function(l, x, envir = parent.frame())
{
    envir[[l]] <- append(envir[[l]], x)
}
```

or pass the objects themselves and return them to avoid dealing with environments:

```
push <- function(l, x) append(l, x)
main <- function() {
  mylist <- list("Hello")
  push(mylist, "World")
}
main()
```